# Node.js -Couchbase - Warning: We are having troubles communicating to the indexer process. The information might be stale

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm using  Couchbase Version 4.1.0-5005 Enterprise Edition (build-5005) and trying to run bikeShop sample but it's not showing the index.

gives me this error

```
 We are having troubles communicating to the indexer process. The information might be stale
```

i opened all ports (for test) as told in  [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html) tutorial but it's get the same error

My OS is win 7

what should i do? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that ports are not opened on the server or on any of the cluster servers.

Try accessing
**`http://SERVER_ADDRESS:9102/getIndexStatus`** with basic auth and the server should return a error message.

Try opening ports 9100, 9101, 9102 and 9999 and then retry with the same url and you will get a success message with list of indexes at couchbase server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a single node cluster?
Did you checked all of the services (Data,Index,Query) in your node?

Thanks,
Roi

Answer (score 0):

For those are working on CB v5.1, try accessing "curl -v -u [user]:[pwd] http://hostname:8091/indexStatus"